# Is there a focus handler in javafx

Tags: focus, javafx, focusmanager

In swing is a FocusManager available to get notified if the focus changes.

```
FocusManager.getCurrentManager().addPropertyChangeListener (...)
```

Is there an analogue way in javafx to get notified if the focus in the scenegraph changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's none yet but you can try manually looping among the focusedProperties of your target nodes

```
private void handleFocusChangesStartingFromParentNode(Parent parentNode) {

    for (Node node : parentNode.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        node.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                performHandling();
            }
        });
        try{
            handleFocusChangesStartingFromNode((Parent)node);
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `ChangeListener` to the [`focusOwner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty%28%29) property of a `Scene` now:

```
scene.focusOwnerProperty().addChangeListener(...)
```