# How do you attach a KeyEvent to a HBox in JavaFX2?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to have a stackpane consume all arrow key events in my application.

```
HBox gcodeTabHbox = new Hbox();

gcodeTabHbox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
               logger.info("KeyPressed");  
            }
});
```

For the life of me I cannot get my event to fire.  I suspect that something else in my application is consuming this?  However I do not know how to check.  Also, I am not sureif the HBox has to be "focused".  I would prefer that when the HBox is visible to the user all KeyEvents would fire to the specific HBox event handler without having to "click" on the HBox first.

Thanks,

Comment: See this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890631/is-there-a-focus-handler-in-javafx

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However I do not understand the reference to that question.